# how to move the messages to deadletter queue in azure service bus based on sequence number in python

Tags: python, azure, azure-servicebus-queues

I want to read the messages from a Azure Service bus queue based on Sequence number and move those messages to deadletter queue

I can able to read the messages from the Service bus queue but not able to mention the Sequence Number while reading.

Answer (score 0):

This option is not provided by the broker/service. The same issue with with the .NET client and a [feature request](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus/issues/453) has been raised to support retrieving messages by sequence number. You might want to add you scenario to the issue to help the team understand the use case.